# How to identify and click on object (X) displayed with EditText field using appium

Tags: selenium, appium-android

The problem

In my app I have a EditText field with X icon at the end. when I manually click on X it removes the field. I want to handle this using my appium script but I didn't find object identification property for X using uiautomatorviewer. Can anyone help?

Environment

Appium version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue: 1.6.5

Last Appium version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable): none

Desktop OS/version used to run Appium: Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Node.js version (unless using Appium.app|exe): 8.3.0

Mobile platform/version under test: Device info: Redmi Note 4, Android Version: 7.0

Real device or emulator/simulator: Real Device

Appium CLI or Appium.app|exe: Appium CLI

screenshot of uiautomatorviewer
[image]

Comment: Try passing the [escape] key to close

Comment: Can you scroll 'node detail' till the end and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved. Got location using getLocation() and then clicked on object.

```
int upperY = element.getLocation().getY();
int lowerY = upperY + element.getSize().getHeight();
int middleY = (upperY + lowerY) / 2;

TouchAction a2 = new TouchAction(driver);
a2.tap(745, 229).perform();
```